# Delete files older than specific file

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos

I need to delete from a folder all files older than a specific file.
Running bash on CentOS 7.

I have a solution for this, but I think there should be a more elegant way do it:

```
reference_file=/my/reference/file

get_modify_time()
{
    stat $1 | grep -Po "Modify: \K[0-9- :]*"
}

pit=$(get_modify_time $reference_file)
for f in /folder/0000* ; do [[ "$pit" > "$(get_modify_time $f)" ]] && rm $f ; done
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but `find` should be able to handle the whole operation just fine:

```
$ find dir/ -type f ! -newer reference -delete
```

... or...

```
$ find dir/ -type f ! -newer reference ! -name reference -delete
```

Basically:

- `! -newer reference` matches files which have been modified less recently than `reference`.
- `-delete` deletes them.
- `! -name reference` excludes `reference`, in case it is also located under `dir/` and you want to keep it.

This should delete all files older than `reference`, and located under `dir/`.

Comment: Perfect :). Just added `-maxdepth 1` to keep the search not recursive

Comment: `! -newer` means "not newer", so "older or *the same age*"; the file itself will be matched if it's in the path `find` looks at, just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @ferada It will not if you exclude it, which is why my answer also includes `! -name reference` (see the third bullet).

Answer (score 8):

compare file modification times with `test`, using `-nt` (newer than) and `-ot` (older than) operators:

```
if [ "$file1" -ot "$file2" ]; then
    #do whatever you want;
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, that's better than my solution but you still need to iterate all files in the folder and compare... The other answer is even more elegant