# How to select files in Midnight Commander using an external command (e.g., `find`)?

Tags: mc

I'm trying to select files that are older than a specific date & time, and found [this MC ticket](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2718) that exactly describes my issue, and [this comment on it](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2718#comment:5) provides a workaround, but I cannot get it to work. To quote:

```
ok, you can use External panalize
0) touch -d "Jun 01 00:00 2011" /tmp/.date1
1) enter into your BIG dir
2) press C-x ! (External panalize )
3) add new command like a "find . -type f \( -newer /tmp/.date1 \) -print"
```

I get stuck at "Add new" and the window just exits; I tried entering something at "Other command", but no joy.

[image: Unable to enter custom commands at CTRL-X !]

[This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186776/delete-files-older-than-specific-file) actually solves what I'm trying to do with `find` on the terminal, but I'm really curious how to do this in MC.